# How can i determine using java what sites have been opened up in browsers?

Tags: java, http, browser

I need to understand the directions in need to look into to Writing a program that figures out what all websites have been hit by a user using his browser. I want to write a standalone program. Can anybody direct me to some API which may help me figure this out.

Comment: Didn't understand part about WAP. Could you clarify?

Comment: Why the negative vote? Please help me understanding whats wrong in the question.

Comment: @sushil: I might ask you the same question.  Do makers of spyware have *no* sense of humor?

Comment: Do you really think that people write spyware in Java? :D

Comment: @Max:  I know that people ask how to get the CPU information in Java.  Java is no better for that, than this.

Comment: Well i dont know where this discussion is heading. All i wanted to write is something like Fiddler. or specifically HTTPAnalyzer for IE. But anyways.

Comment: @sushil bharwani: So it is ok for app to run in the background and scan what user is **currently** browsing, not the history of all the clicks? That makes it much much easier. You need that? Or the history scanner?

Comment: @max No no, not the histroy scanner. I need a app to run in background and scan what the user is currently browsing.

Comment: @sushil bharwani: Then you should specify in your question, currently it sounds like you need a history scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was clarified by the author in his comments - he needs to check what is user currently browsing.

The only truly browser and OS independent way is through proxy. You need to create a HTTP(S) proxy with Java (there are some implementations out there already) and then reconfigure the desired browser to use the proxy running at localhost. When your proxy is used - it will be able to track every bit of traffic the user tries to load.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all that depends on which browser do you need to check. I'm guessing that you need to check the currently set default system browser. Anyway, that will require a lot of browser research and few JNI calls.

1. To find a default browser you would need to check `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command` (for Windows) and various configuration files under different linux for different window managers.
2. Then you would need to read the history of the specific browser from the format of that browser. For example, Firefox stores it's history in `sqlite` format in the profile directory in `places.sqlite` file. Chrome on other hand stores it in `%home%/User Data/Default/history`. So you would need a separate parser for each browser.

Basically, if you need a universal browser history reader - it's a load of work and research.

Answer (score 0):

This information is stored in a SQLite database in firefox:

> The file "places.sqlite" stores the annotations, bookmarks, favorite
>   icons, input history, keywords, and browsing history (a record of
>   visited pages).

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite

Other browsers probably have similar approaches.

Any language with drivers for SQLite, and that includes Java, C, C#, C++, ruby, and, yes, even javascript, should be equally capable of accessing this database.

Speaking for myself, I would be interested collaborating on such a stand-alone program in Java should the OP put his code on github.